# Is there a request limit for firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have been trying to find how many requests can be made to a static website hosted via firebase but I can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits to the number of requests.  In terms of cost, everything you need to know is on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).  Pricing has nothing to do with the volume of requests.

Comment: I guess a better way to ask this question is what would incur a cost from delivering content to users? Is the RTDB downloads limit the main concern? Or am I completely off base? Thanks btw

Comment: Database charges are completely separate from hosting charges.  There's no way to know what will be the biggest expense until you understand the usage patterns of your app.

Comment: Oh apologies, I misspoke. I meant the GB transferred for hosting then. Is that referring to page size downloaded by the end user?

Comment: It's the total number of bytes downloaded, for all files and assets that you serve.

Comment: Ok that is more along the lines of what I was looking for but clearly didn't understand lol. Thanks for clarifying this for me!